# alternate of intersect set operator in oracle

Tags: oracle, set, operators, intersect

I have a table emp1 wherein I am interested in only the employees who have joined with salary less than 2000 and whose salary is greater than 2000 now. This is the case with only one person Ward as shown below. I prepared the answer with intersect but wanted to know if there is more efficient way of doing it .Please let me know that will be of great help to me

(select empno,deptno
from emp1
where sal<2000
group by empno,hiredate,deptno
)
intersect
(select empno,deptno
from emp1
where sal>2000
group by empno,hiredate,deptno
)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: First clarify the problem. In your code you find employees whose lowest salary was or is less than 2000 and highest salary was or is greater than 2000. This is not the same as "joined with" salary < 2000 and "current" salary > 2000, **unless** you assume (and that is a strong assumption that you should state, if you are making that assumption) that salary always goes up over time, never down. So - please clarify.

Comment: Thanks mathguy let me put it this way I want persons who joined with salary less than 2000 and now has salary greater than say 2500. Since there is only one person who satisfies this condition in my emp table I want the count of employees to be 1. Please let me know if it makes sense, others also have salary >2500 but they have joined with that salary so I am not considering them.

Comment: OK, so your current query doesn't do that - it only looks for "least" and "greatest" salaries, not "earliest" and "most recent".

Answer (score 2):

First, here's how you can get the specific employees who satisfy your conditions (as modified in a comment): Earliest salary < 2000, current (most recent) salary > 2500. Note that in my sample data employee 1008 started at 1300 and had salary > 2500 at some point, but his **current** salary is < 2500 so he is not selected.

The query is as efficient as possible: it performs a standard aggregation and nothing else. The conditions are in the `having` clause. The `first/last` aggregate function, even though it is exceptionally useful, is ignored by a vast majority of programmers - for no good reason.

```
with
  sal_hist (empno, sal_date, sal) as (
    select 1003, date '2000-01-01', 2300 from dual union all
    select 1003, date '2008-01-01', 2600 from dual union all
    select 1008, date '2002-03-20', 1300 from dual union all
    select 1008, date '2005-01-31', 2600 from dual union all
    select 1008, date '2013-11-01', 2400 from dual union all
    select 2025, date '2008-03-01', 1900 from dual union all
    select 2025, date '2015-04-01', 2550 from dual
  )
select empno
from   sal_hist
group  by empno
having min(sal) keep (dense_rank first order by sal_date) < 2000
   and min(sal) keep (dense_rank last  order by sal_date) > 2500
;

     EMPNO
----------
      2025
```

To get the count of such employees, wrap the above query within an outer query, with `select count(*) as my_count from ( <above query> )`.

For extra credit, try to understand why the following query also works. It's more compact (and possibly faster, even though not by much), but a bit harder to understand - and especially, to understand why I need `min(empno)` rather than simply `empno` or `*` within the `count()` call.

```
select count(min(empno)) as my_count
from   sal_hist
group  by empno
having min(sal) keep (dense_rank first order by sal_date) < 2000
   and min(sal) keep (dense_rank last  order by sal_date) > 2500
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mathguy much appreciated.